# C: Problems with using getchar and switch case to get user input for a main menu

Tags: c, switch-statement, getchar

I know there are many threads similar to this one, however, those threads didn't really help me out. I am new to C, so I might be just making a silly mistake, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I am trying to create a main menu like this:

```
Main menu:

1. Play
2. Reset
3. Display
```

When users press 1, I want it to print play game, when 2 is pressed, I want it to print Reset, and so on.
However, with my code, when user presses 1, it prints "play game", and when users presses 2 or 3, it doesn't print anything.

```
int main(){

    int input;

    /*Displays the menu to user*/

    printf("Main menu\n");
    printf("1.Play\n");
    printf("2.Reset\n");
    printf("3.Display\n");   
    printf("please enter something:\n");

    input=getchar();

    switch(input){
    case'1':
        printf("play game\n");
        break;
    case'2':
        printf("reset\n");
        break;
    case'3':
        printf("Display\n");   
        break;
    default:
        printf("invalid\n");
        break;
    }

    {
        getchar();
        while(input != '3');
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So I know I might be making a silly mistake, but I just can't figure what I am doing wrong. I have also looked at other threads and none them have helped me.

Comment: `while(input != '3');` : You can not escape from this loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `do-while` loop. You want to nest your `switch` inside this `do-while` to repeatedly execute it.

Also, note the extra `getchar()` call to consume the `Enter` that was typed after the number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int input;

    /*Displays the menu to user*/

    printf("Main menu\n");
    printf("1.Play\n");
    printf("2.Reset\n");
    printf("3.Display\n");   
    printf("please enter something:\n");


    do{
        input=getchar();
        getchar();
        switch(input){
            case'1':
                printf("play game\n");
                break;
            case'2':
                printf("reset\n");
                break;
            case'3':
                printf("Display\n");   
                break;
            default:
                printf("invalid\n");
                break;
        }

    } while(input != '3');
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it was the do-while loop! It makes sense now. Thank you